# GRUB not showing up (windows 10/ubuntu)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

So, on my HP650 i have internal HDD on which i have windows 10.
I installed Ubuntu 18.04. on external HDD which is connected via USB.

The problem is that GRUB menu doesn't show up at start, so I can't choose which OS to run, it goes to windows. Only way i can boot Ubuntu is manually, by pressing esc during startup, entering boot device options, and selecting Ubuntu.

[image: boot device options]

These are boot options and boot order in bios
[image]

I also tried changing boot order in Ubuntu terminal with no luck.

I disabled fast startup in windows.

Any ideas?

Comment: May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please attach link to the summary report, the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: @oldfred http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/fxySRYDSgw

Comment: Your system seems to promote external drive to sda, and then internal becomes sdb. But you have Windows installed in UEFI boot mode on gpt partitioned drive on internal drive. And you installed Ubuntu in UEFI mode but to a MBR(msdos) partitioned drive. UEFI highly recommends you use gpt. And if you ever want to boot external drive separately you have to partition in advance using gpt. http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu &  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI You need an ESP - efi system partition on external drive with gpt partitioning.

Answer (score 1):

In the BIOS set up make the external HDD as first option.

Command:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Opens the file "grub". Comment out the line

```
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
```

If `GRUB_TIMEOUT=0` make it `GRUB_TIMEOUT=10`

set `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu` if it is not already set. (Grub new versions)

save and close the file

Run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: timeouts was already at 10

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @oldfred, i reinstalled ubuntu and created partitions using gpt and everything works fine, grub shows up on startup.
First time I installed ubuntu, i followed ubuntu installer, and he does not offer gpt option, so now i used gparted. Now i created efi partirion which i didnt made the first time i was partitioning the disk.

Thank again!